# Google Map Gateway Timeout with PHP

Tags: google-maps, php

I've HTML form with 5 fields.

1) Address 2) city 3) state 4) country 5) postcode.

After input this field value it's show Google map.

**Google map code:**

```
<?php
$add = urlencode($_POST['address']);
$city = urlencode($_POST['city']);
$state = urlencode($_POST['state']);
$country  = urlencode($_POST['country']);
$zip = $_POST['zip'];

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode   
/json?address='.$add.',+'.$city.',+'.$state.',+'.$country.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable

if($output->status == 'OK'){ // Check if address is available or not
echo "<br/>";
echo "Latitude : ".$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; //Returns Latitude
echo "<br/>";
echo "Longitude : ".$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; // Returns Longitude
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Define the latitude and longitude positions
var latitude = parseFloat("<?php echo $lat; ?>"); // Latitude get from above variable
var longitude = parseFloat("<?php echo $long; ?>"); // Longitude from same
var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
// Set up options for the Google map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 10,
center: latlngPos,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoomControlOptions: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
}
};
// Define the map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
// Add the marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlngPos,
map: map,
title: "test"
});
});
</script>
<div id="map" style="width:450px;height:350px; margin-top:10px;"></div> // Div in which 
Google   Map will show
<?php
}
?>
```

But after submit in process page it's show following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode
>       /json?address=,+Dhaka,+,+Bangladesh&sensor=false): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
>       HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Timeout in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-website
>       \lat-long.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-
>       website\lat-long.php on line 23

What is the wrong in my code? Is there anyone help me?
Thanks.

**No helpful answered!**

Comment: It does not look like that anything is wrong with your code. More with the gateway: *"HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Timeout"*

Comment: Well, @hakre so what need to do to fix it?

Comment: Have you contacted the operator of the gateway and reported the problem to them? Because I would ask there first, not me. I'm not running that gateway for you, you know? ;)

Comment: check `allow_url_fopen` on or off in php.ini

Comment: @Alex: No, you are using `maps.google.com`.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia's article on HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> **504 Gateway Timeout**
>
> The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

So, either you have a proxy server sitting between you and the internet, and it returned this error, or the Google Maps server(s) you're hitting are non-responsive and their reverse proxies / load balancers can't serve you the page in time.

Speak to your web hosting provider about any proxy server they might be using.  As it looks like this is on your local PC, then chances are that your "web hosting provider" is either your IT department (business, school) or your ISP (home user).  If they aren't using a proxy, then the problem probably isn't on your end and isn't under your control.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        $arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        ); 

        $geocode=file_get_contents(
            'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$add.',+'.$city.',+'.$state.',+'.$country.'&sensor=false', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)
        );
```

Comment: The last line seems to have escaped from the code block. Indent code with four spaces to create a code block.

Comment: Care to explain why this should help?